# Importacion Data con Laravel Excel pero si imgreso el mismo con otro campo actualizado me dice que esta duplicado no me actualiza

Tags: php, laravel, excel

¿Mi pregunrta es tengo una importacion de data con laravel excel quiero actualizar la data ya registrada atraves del archivo y no que me cree un id nuevo xq voy a tener 2 veces la misma imformacion o cada vez que la importe me va a colocar de nuevo.

ejemplo :  importacion 1 = data 1 id=1 nombre apellido telefono
           importacion 2 = data 1 id=2 nombre apellido telefono (pero le estoy colocando el mismo archivo quiero actualizar la primera data

** Este Es mi Controlador**

```
public function import()
    {   

        Excel::import(new UsersImport,request()->file('file'));      

        return redirect('#')->with('success', 'All good!');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba de la siguente manera

UsersImport.php

```
class UsersImport implements toModel
{
    public function model(array $row)
    {
        return new User([
            'name' => $row[1],
            'email' => $row[2],
            'password' => $row[3],

        ]);
    }
}
```

Metodo import() en tu controlador

```
public function import(Request $request)
{
    $users =  Excel::toCollection(new new UsersImport,request()->file('file'));

    foreach($users[0] as $user)
    {
        User::where('id', $user[0])->update([
            'name' => $user[1],
            'email' => $user[2]
        ])
    }

    return redirect('#')->with('success', 'All good!');
}
```

Espero te sirva

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esto dentro de tu controlador, donde recives el archivo a traves del input type="file"

```
public function importExcel(Request $request)
{       
    $file = $request->file('file');

    foreach($users[0] as $user)
    {
        User::where('id', $user[0])->update
        ([
             'name' => $user[1],
             'email' => $user[2]
        ])
    }

    Excel::import(new UsersImport, $file);
    return redirect()->route('AQUI VA EL NOMBRE DE TU VISTA')->with('info', 'Importación realizada con éxito');
}
```

Y esto en tu modelo de importación: UsersImport

```
public function model(array $row)
{
    return new User([
        'name' => $row['name'],//a
        'email' => $row['name'], //b
        'password' => $row['password'], //c
    ]);
}
```

Hay que aclarar que esa importación es mediante nombres de columnas, es decir. la funcion busca el nombre de la celda e inserta todo lo relacionado a ella, para esto tienes que importar `use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadingRow;` e implementarla en esta linea: `class ProductsImport implements ToModel, WithHeadingRow`

si solo quieres insertar directo por celdas, sin nombre de la columna, puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
    public function model(array $row)
{
    return new User([
        'name' => $row[0],//a
        'email' => $row[1], //b
        'password' => $row[2], //c
    ]);
}
```

Yo estoy trabajando con algo así, y te puedo asegurar que esto funciona.